# Can I send others the third-party Python packages I installed?

Tags: python, package

I have code on an offline computer, so I needed to install dependency packages offline (which I myself figured out how to only yesterday). Now, I want to send my work to my teammates (it's a school project and half of them are first-time programmers), whether directly or through Github. I want to send them the packages I was using too, just in case they needed to do offline installation.

Is it possible to just zip up the dependency packages as-is and send it to them to unzip to the relevant directory? Where are these packages installed to? Are there other files that need to be sent? Or is there no other way than to run the python/pip install on the wheels/tar.gz I downloaded from PyPi (the solution I'm trying to avoid)?

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid using dependency managers? This is exactly the kind of thing they're for.

Comment: @Chris Well I don't know how to set one up, for one. And the team leader with 3x longer work experience decided, for a 4-week assignment of this application size (our team's 6 pax and not enough coding work to assign as it is), it's not worth the hassle of setting up something so complex. he specifically opted for Github over Maven. Ultimately I'm only sending them my code to run on their computers, they ain't even gonna modify the code I'll be sending them, so I'm not gonna dispute that.

Comment: So complex? As long as you have a semi-recent Python you've already got `pip`, and it's very simple to use. Spend five minutes on Google and learn. Dependency managers are important.

Comment: @Chris I know how to use pip. The issue is installing them offline - for the teammates who've never touched code until a couple weeks ago.

Comment: "The issue is installing them offline"—that's a _much_ better reason than "I don't know how to set one up". (`pip` _is_ a dependency manager. If you know how to use it with `requirements.txt` you've got the basics already.) Look up packaging tools. There can still be architectural and OS issues, but it is possible to package up Python applications if you need to. Go into that knowing as much as possible about the target machines. If you can limit them to a specific version of a specific OS on a specific architecture and build on the same you'll have the best luck.

Comment: @Chris Well I figured out how to work with wheels etc. yesterday. My issue is trying to install these packages on the other folks' computers. So are you saying that's the only way to go about it? Installing the wheels etc.? I can't just go to the installed folders in my computer, zip them up, then give that to them?

Comment: I'm saying that that _might_ work, depending on your OS and hardware and their OS and hardware, but that it's not entirely reliable. `pip install -r requirements.txt` (or other similar commands using `pip-tools` or Pipenv) is better.

Comment: hmm ok, I guess I'll just have to go for that and see how it turns out. Thanks anyway!

Comment: This is also highly dependent on the specific libraries you're trying to copy. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of virtualenv for this purpose: https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/index.html

It will install dependencies inside a folder, so you can zip or share in many ways.

Comment: Virtualenvs aren't portable. Zipping them up and moving them from machine to machine isn't a good idea.

Comment: If machines share SO it is possible, but yes, maybe not the best idea, just a workaround.

Comment: It _can_ work, but it's not reliable. Personally I wouldn't want to recommend an unpredictable, buggy strategy...

Answer (score 0):

The folder you are looking for is 'site-packages' or 'dist-packages', you can put packages in here for use in python on a machine without a package manager.

The default directory for packages on windows is:

```
C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\
```

The default directory for packages on linux is:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```